# Does "at the margin" mean "however" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“London will remain a major financial center,” he said. “**At the margin** there will some shift to other financial centers in Europe.”

If not, what does it mean?

source: http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-09-06/forget-paris-singapore-seen-as-best-business-hub-after-london

Comment: This question may be closed, but if you will simply look up _margin_ in any dictionary, the meaning you find there will apply to this usage. In other words, to understand this usage, you must know what the word [**margin**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/margin?s=t) means. What dictionary did you use?

Comment: Are you asking about the construction "***at the*** margin" rather than the meaning of "margin"? If so edit you question and make it more specific.

Comment: @xxxxxx "At the margin" is not idiomatic. It uses _margin_ in its usual sense as defined in any dictionary.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - ok, so could I say *on the margin* or *in the margin*  also?

Comment: No. Read and understand the meaning of _margin,_ and the usage is clear. _Margin_ means any edge or border. This is not difficult. It does require reading and understanding the dictionary entry in several dictionaries: in other words: research.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I think it is idiomatic:          ***Thinking  at the margin:*** Economists often talk about "thinking at the margin" -- you might even hear them say "***everything happens at the margin***." What does that actually mean?http://www.theconceptsproject.com/thinking-at-the-margin/#.V9EXzZiLShc

Comment: @xxxxxx What does that actually mean?  It actually means **Everything happens _at the edge or border._** This comports perfectly with the dictionary definition of _margin._

Comment: @P.E.Dant: You should read this: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071230123621AANi5jZ

Comment: I don't see anything at the Yahoo site that adds to the discussion. Once you visualize what a _margin_ is, any expression that uses the word is understandable. A margin is a border area. Thinking "at the margin" means simply thinking outside of the center: at the edge. There are specialized meanings of _margin_ in financial jargon ("margin call" e.g.) but the example in your question does not partake of that special meaning.